# How to run a program forever?

Tags: javascript

I've got got a stupid question, can you help me please?
I want this program to run and run and run. At this moment after each try I have to refresh page to play again and it sucks.

"8. Write a JavaScript program where the program takes a random integer between 1 to 10, the user is then prompted to input a guess number. If the user input matches with guess number, the program will display a message "Good Work" otherwise display a message "Not matched"."

Here's what I've got:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
var guessNumber = prompt("enter a number between 1 and 10");
if (guessNumber == randomNumber) {
alert("Good work!");
} else {
alert("Looser! The number was " + randomNumber);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Put it in an endless loop:

```
while (true) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    var guessNumber = prompt("enter a number between 1 and 10");
    if (guessNumber == randomNumber) {
        alert("Good work!");
    } else {
        alert("Loser! The number was " + randomNumber);
    }
}
```

**but**, I wouldn't do that. I'd offer a way to get out:

```
while (true) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    var guessNumber = prompt("enter a number between 1 and 10");
    if (!guessNumber) {                                // ***
        break;                                         // ***
    }                                                  // ***
    if (guessNumber == randomNumber) {
        alert("Good work!");
    } else {
        alert("Loser! The number was " + randomNumber);
    }
}
```

If the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the `prompt`, `guessNumber` will be `""` or `null` (depending on the browser), both of which are falsy, so you'll break out of the loop.

---

Side note: "Loser" has only one "o" in it, and control-flow statements with attached blocks don't have `;` after the block.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your code into the `while (true)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

just make an infinite loop

```
var run = true

while (run)
 {
    console.log('foobar');
 }
```

never set run as false and your loop will never stop